# Why do I get empty objects when pushing to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following snippet:

```
var options = [];
$("tr.mks-option-row").each(function (row) {
    options.push({
        Id: $(row).data("option-id"),
        CategoryId: $(row).data("category-id"),
        Value: $(row).data("option-text")
    });
});
```

Where `.mks-option-row` is the selector for all the rows in a table. The table contains several elements of data, which I have also repeated as data-attributes on the `tr` itself.

However, when this snippet is done, the `options` array contains `n` empty object literals. If there are 4 rows in the table the array contains `[{},{},{},{}]`

What am I doing wrong here? (I have also tried using quoted identifiers with no difference in outcome)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(row, $(row))`

Comment: If you can add the html code, it will help to answer.

Comment: This is not possible. Even if the data wasn't being found, you'd be getting `{ Id: undefined, CategoryId: undefined, Value: undefined }`. Are you checking the output using `JSON.stringify`? That might explain it. Please post how you are getting `[{},{},{},{}]`, and also post an example HTML which lets us reconstruct your result.

Comment: syntax of `$.each` is `$.each(index, element)`. Just rectify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `row` is passed as the element index in the list of rows to the callback function, you need to use `this` in order to fetch the row as jquery object:

```
var options = [];
$("tr.mks-option-row").each(function () {
    options.push({
        Id: $(this).data("option-id"),
        CategoryId: $(this).data("category-id"),
        Value: $(this).data("option-text")
    });
});
```

**Update:**

More specifically, `$.each` expects `function(index, element)`. this is one option; ignoring the first argument is another.

```
$("tr.mks-option-row").each(function (row, element) {
     options.push({
         Id: $(element).data("option-id"),
         CategoryId: $(element).data("category-id"),
         Value: $(element).data("option-text")
     });
});
```

Comment: More specifically, `$.each` expects `function(index, element)`. `this` is one option; ignoring the first argument is another.

Comment: Now I just feel like a fool... I should know this, but in the heat of the moment it escaped me. And I don't like to use ``this`` too much because I feel like I can't control it. However, if you edit your answer to use ``function (idx, row) {`` I'll give it to you. The element is passed as the second parameter and index as the first. Your answer put me on the right track...

Comment: @Amadan: But you're right. It still doesn't explain why I didn't just get the objects with ``undefined`` as each property's value or something like that...